# How to make padding gradually decrease on viewport resize in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

So I want to make a padding-left of my box to gradually decrease as you change website width, and for it to stop decreasing as padding reaches 0.

For example, when you change screen size by 1px, then padding-left should also decrease by 1px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `calc` + `viewport units properties`:

**Example**

```
body {
  // padding grows 1px for every 100px of viewport width
  padding-left: calc(0px + 1vw);
}
```

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: This answers a similar question I had, thanks! I assume in this example the viewport would need to be less than 100px wide to reach a padding value of 0. But let's say I wanted 0 padding when the parent container is 500px wide, and padding of 100px (roughly) when the container is 1000px wide?